# Model.query() returns "undefined" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

On the Sailsjs console, I'm attempting to perform raw SQL queries using Waterline/Sails's ***[query()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query)*** method on a ***MySQL*** database. However, I keep receiving the error message:

```
 
sails> User.query('SELECT id from user').exec(console.log)
TypeError: Cannot call method 'exec' of undefined
    at repl:1:37
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:112:21)
    at Interface. (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:203:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:532:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:761:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:100:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1096:12)
```

Running Waterline's other methods such as ***[find()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find)*** execute successfully.

```
 
sails> User.find().exec(console.log)
undefined
sails> null [ { email: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    name: 'xxxx',
   }]
```

Internet searches indicated that the ***sails-mysql*** adapter should be used for the connection; that's what I'm using and the issue still persists.

My ***config/connections.js*** file

```
 
module.exports.connections = {
  default_dev_mysql_server: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxx'}
}
```

My ***config/models.js*** file

```
 
module.exports.models = {
  schema: true,
  connection: 'default_dev_mysql_server',
  migrate: 'safe'

};
```

I'm running ***sails-mysql v0.11.2*** and ***sails v0.11.2***, which are the most stable versions of the software.

What other settings am I missing to be able to perform raw SQL queries on Sailsjs? Google hasn't been very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` is necessary when using ORM features, as internally, it builds up a SQL statement to be `exec`cuted at a later stage. `query` on the other hand, accepts a string SQL statement and a callback as its parameters, and has no use for `exec`, hence its undefined. Try this instead:

```
User.query('SELECT id from user', function(err, res){
  console.log(err, res);
});
```

Comment: Wow! If I had paid more attention to the examples, I could have actually seen that ***exec()*** wasn't used with query() while it was used for the other features. Thanks very much for the assistance.